# Include css from node_module(npm package)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gulp, node-modules

I use React on client, and i need include css from npm package.
Before I took them and copied to my local directorie with style.

I also use GULP in the working draft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gulp to copy files from `node_modules` as part of your build:

```
var srcPath = "node_modules/whatever/stylesheets/*.css";
var buildPath = "folder/that/gets/served/to/client";
gulp.task("build-html", function () {
    return gulp.src(srcPath).pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));
});
```